# How to prove triangle inequality for essential supremum ($\text{esssup}(f+g)\le \text{esssup}(f)+\text{esssup}(g)$)?

Tags: real-analysis

I find [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511384/how-to-prove-essential-supremum-is-a-norm) when I working on my work, but when I follow it I am having difficulty to prove the triangle inequality, which seems to be quite straightforward. 
That is, want to show $\text{esssup}(f+g)\le \text{esssup}(f)+\text{esssup}(g)$

Comment: you mean, proving that $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$?

Comment: @Vasya Yes. And the norm is taking essential supremum.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I realize it is easy, same as the non-essential prof.

First we see that for $f$ and $g$, we have $\text{esssup}(f)\le f$ almost everywhere, which lead to $\text{esssup}(f) + \text{esssup}(g)\le f+g$. Thus, we see $\text{esssup}(f) + \text{esssup}(g) \in \{z:f+g\le z \text{ a.e.}\}$, Thus $\text{esssup}(f) + \text{esssup}(g) \ge \text{inf}\{z:f+g\le z \text{ a.e.}\} = \text{esssup}(f+g)$.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the essential suprema of $|f|$ and $|g|$ are  $a$ and $b$ respectively.   Thus $|f(x)| \le a$ outside a set $A$ of measure $0$, and $|g(x)| \le b$ outside a set $B$ of measure $0$.  Then $A \cup B$ has measure $0$, and outside it we have
$|f(x) + g(x)| \le |f(x)| + |g(x)| \le a + b$, so the essential supremum of $|f+g|$ is at most $a+b$.